Failed to compile, using react-pdf with nextjs
Im trying to implement this following package in my nextjs project
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf
I've followed every instruction to best of my capabilities and I keep getting failed to compile
i have turbopack enabled for dev
./node_modules/react-pdf/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.mjs:11881:28
Module not found
  11879 |         return this.#mainThreadWorkerMessageHandler;
  11880 |       }
> 11881 |       const worker = await import( /*webpackIgnore: true*/this.workerSrc);
        |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  11882 |       return worker.WorkerMessageHandler;
  11883 |     };
  11884 |     return shadow(this, "_setupFakeWorkerGlobal", loader());

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

this is my next.config.js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        turbo: {
            resolveAlias: {
                canvas: './empty-module.ts',
            },
        },


    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig


this is my empty.module.ts
export default {};

in my layout ive added
import { pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = new URL(
    'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.min.js',
    import.meta.url,
).toString();

I have also tried with cdn
inside my pdf viewer component I just used the same examplecode as provided in readme
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';

function Pdfpreview() {
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState<number>();
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState<number>(1);

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }: { numPages: number }): void {
    setNumPages(numPages);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Document file="somefile.pdf" onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
        <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
      </Document>
      <p>
        Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

I have copied pdf.worker.min.mjs to my public folder I still get the same error
Any help would be much appreciated thx in advance
Tried to use cdn, tried to copy the worker to public, use cdn, move the import options to layout and inside the pdfpreview component. I have tried "use client" on both the layout and pdfpreview component still no luck always the same error "failed to compile"
